# How to use multithreading with turtle module

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading, turtle-graphics

Here is piece I've been working on lately. The task of the project is to create three symbols as the vertices of a triangle. The symbols will always move, with equal velocity, towards each other(i.e. 1-->2, 2-->3, 3-->1). As the symbols start moving simultaneously, the final figure must look like this

[image]

Here is my code. I'm using multi-threading to call all three methods simultaneously but the program doesn't seem to work as it should be. The methods are executing themselves separately, one after another, which shouldn't be happening.

```
import turtle
import time
import threading


class TurObj:

    def __init__(self, x, y, color, speed):
        self.t = turtle.Pen()
        self.t.ht()
        self.t.shape('circle')
        self.t.fillcolor(color)
        self.t.speed(speed)
        self.t.penup()
        self.t.goto(x, y)
        self.t.pendown()
        self.t.st()

    def get_loc(self):
        cor = [self.t.xcor(), self.t.ycor()]
        return cor

    def move_to(self, n):
        #  self.t.setx(n.get_loc().__getitem__(0))
        #  self.t.sety(n.get_loc().__getitem__(1))
        self.t.goto(n.get_loc().__getitem__(0), n.get_loc().__getitem__(1))


t1 = TurObj(300, 200, 'red', 5)
t2 = TurObj(-300, 200, 'yellow', 5)
t3 = TurObj(0, -200, 'blue', 5)

p1 = threading.Thread(target=t1.move_to(t2))
p2 = threading.Thread(target=t2.move_to(t3))
p3 = threading.Thread(target=t3.move_to(t1))

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()

time.sleep(3)
```

Any help would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always recommend trying turtle's own `ontimer()` event before considering threads.  Your code also seems to jump too far with a `goto()` rather than take small steps with a `setheading(towards())` and `forward()` combination.  Finally, your starting positions don't appear to be symmetric.  Below is my rework addressing these issues:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class TurtleObject:

    def __init__(self, position, color, speed):
        self.t = Turtle(shape='circle', visible=False)
        self.t.fillcolor(color)
        self.t.speed(speed)
        self.t.penup()
        self.t.goto(position)
        self.t.pendown()
        self.t.showturtle()

    def get_turtle(self):
        return self.t

    def on_top_of(self, n):
        other = n.get_turtle()
        return abs(self.t.xcor() - other.xcor()) < 5 and abs(self.t.ycor() - other.ycor()) < 5

    def move_towards(self, n):
        self.t.setheading(self.t.towards(n.get_turtle()))
        self.t.forward(1)

        if not self.on_top_of(n):
            screen.ontimer(lambda: self.move_towards(n), 100)


t1 = TurtleObject((300, 200), 'red', "fast")
t2 = TurtleObject((-300, 200), 'yellow', "fast")
t3 = TurtleObject((0, -320), 'blue', "fast")

screen = Screen()

screen.ontimer(lambda: t1.move_towards(t2), 100)
screen.ontimer(lambda: t2.move_towards(t3), 100)
screen.ontimer(lambda: t3.move_towards(t1), 100)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]